# How to pass attributes from jQuery to Rails using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to implement a Rails 3.2 drag and drop shopping cart using jQuery (`$.ajax`).

**Problem:**
I can't figure out how to pass my `line_items` controller a `:product_id` option in JavaScript. I believe Ajax is the key, so that's where my heads at right now. Currently, this is easily done in HTML using a `button_to` with embedded ruby like so:

```
(<%= button_to('Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id => product), :remote => true) %>)
```

However to implement the drag/drop function, the above action needs to be triggered upon a `drop`. How can this be done in JavaScript?

**My controller:**

```
# POST /line_items
# POST /line_items.json
def create
     @cart = current_cart
     product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
     @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)

     respond_to do |format|
     if @line_item.save
     format.html { redirect_to(store_index_url) }
     format.js   { @current_item = @line_item }
     format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, :location => @line_item }
     else
     format.html { render :action => "new" }
     format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
   end
end
```

**My HTML:**

```
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
     <div class="entry" data-id="<%= product.id %>">
       <h3><%= product.title %> </h3>
       <%= image_tag(product.image_url)%>
       <div style="display: none; width: 10px"><%= sanitize(product.description) %>   </div>
       <div class="price_line">
         <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>(<%= product.unit_of_measure%>)
     <br>
     <%= button_to('Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id => product), :remote => true) %>
   </div>
 </div>
   <p>
<%  end %>
```

**My Javascript:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //End Navigation Buttons
    var dragDrop;

$('.entry').draggable({
    revert: true ,
    revertDuration: 500,
    containment: "document", 
    zIndex: 100, 
    helper: "clone",
    start: function(){
        dragDrop = $(this).data('id');
    }
});

$('#cart').droppable({
    accept: '.entry',
    activeClass: 'active',
    hoverClass: 'hovered',
    drop: function( event, ui ){
        $.post({
           url: "<%= escape_javascript(line_items_path(:product_id => product)) %>"
        });
    }
});
...
```

So far the drag works and the drop works except there is no `:product_id` passed to `line_items`. I just get `ERROR bad URI '/store/[object Object]'.` in my command console when I drop an item.

Answer (score 0):

The post function should be:

```
$.post({
   url: "<%= escape_javascript(line_items_path(:product_id => product.id)) %>"
});
```

Note `product.id` instead of `product`

Comment: Hmm, I made the switch but am still getting the 'ERROR bad URI /store/[object%20Object]' error. Could the issue be with my routes then? Why is a call to '/store/...' requested? doesn't line_items_path post to '/line_items' as my routes confirm? Thanks

Comment: BOOYA - figured it out. Instead of escaping to rails, I used the following ajax:

Comment: $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/line_items?',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
     xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
    data: {product_id: dragDrop, remote: true},
    dataType: "script"
   });